# Reading, writing and searching through text files with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm stuck with Qt (again) and I'm trying to read text from a text file. Here is what the text file contains:

```
1001 James Bark
1002 Jeremy Parker
1003 Seinfeld Parker
1004 Sigfried FonStein
1005 Rabbun Hassan
1006 Jenniffer Jones
1007 Agent Smith
1008 Mister Anderson
```

Don't ask where the names came from. I need to be able to index this file and add it to a table. The table, as of now, looks like this:

```
|--------------------------------|
|          |First Name|Last Name | 
|--------------------------------|
|1001      |          |          |  
|--------------------------------| 
|          |          |          |
|--------------------------------|      
|          |          |          |
|--------------------------------|      
|          |          |          |      
|--------------------------------|
```

But it needs to look like this

```
    |--------------------------------|
    |          |First Name|Last Name | 
    |--------------------------------|
    |1001      |James     |Bark      |  
    |--------------------------------| 
    |1002      |Jeremy    |Parker    |
    |--------------------------------|      
    |1003      |Seinfeld  |FonStein  |
    |--------------------------------|      
    |1004      |Rabbun    |Hassan    |      
    |--------------------------------|
```

The table part and putting the items in is not a problem. The problem lies in reading a text file that is formatted like the example at the top. Also, I don't need it to be formatted like that. I could have 3 different text files with ID, Fname, and Lname seperated in those files. This would be a hassle, but if I have to do this I will.

So my question is how the hell do I index through this file and get these values?

Here's a function:

```
Function(){
    QString fileName = "C:\\Users\\Gabe\\SeniorProj\\Students.txt";
    QFile mFile(fileName);

    if(!mFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)){
        qDebug() << "Could not open file for reading";
        return;
    }

    QTextStream in(&mFile);
    QString mText = in.readAll();

    mFile.flush();
    mFile.close();
    }
```

This code I got from some tutorial somewhere. Everything works, I've checked if I can access the file, and all is good. But what to do with it... I have a string equal to all of the text. That's not very useful. So I tried stuff I used in c++, like `mFile.nextInt();` Well that function doesn't exist!!!

How do I search through a text file for specific things in Qt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That file format will cause you a lot of trouble if the names can contain spaces, because you cannot know whether the first name or the last contains two parts. Consider using some other character as a separator, for example:

```
1001;James;Bark
1002;Jeremy;Parker
1003;Seinfeld;Parker
```

Then read the lines one at a time (see QTextStream's documentation) and split the QString to QStringList:

```
QTextStream stream(stdin);
QString line;    
do {
    line = stream.readLine();
    QStringList parts = line.split(";", QString::KeepEmptyParts);
    if (parts.length() == 3) {
        QString id        = parts[0];
        QString firstName = parts[1];
        QString lastName  = parts[2];
    }        
} while (!line.isNull());
```